# libreoffice calc: third argument to be checked

Tags: openoffice-calc

I had troubles to find out how to test a third value that sometimes is present in my spreadsheet.
This i have and it works for 2 Values (means the "standart"-case or if "I" is a numeric Value...):

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(I7); I7*J7; E7*G7)
```

In the column C, if a third value with the name: "freddyfox" is present, then do this math instead: E/G (divide, ...as said instead of the above (I * J or else E * G).

i have tryed things like this...

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(I7); I7*J7; E7*G7, IF(AND(C7=freddyfox); E7/G7) ))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use `AND`.  Instead, put the second `IF` in the 'true' result of the first `IF`.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(I7); IF(C7="freddyfox"; E7/G7; I7*J7); E7*G7)
```

This yields E7/G7 when `ISNUMBER(I7)` and `C7="freddyfox"`.  If `ISNUMBER(I7)` but not `C7="freddyfox"` then it yields I7*J7, and if neither is true, then it yields E7*G7.

**EDIT**:

Here is the formula requested in the comment.

```
=IF(C7="freddyfox"; E7/G7; IF(ISNUMBER(I7); I7*J7; E7*G7))
```

Comment: .Seems working. Problem, i have to change the whole statment because it should testing 3 times 1 value... i mean like something like this: If "freddyfox" then E7/G7- if "isnumber" then I7*J7-if "neither" is true, then E7*G7. Thank's for your help!

Comment: Yes it works now as exceptet. (I Thought i had tried this, may the syntax was not correct -Tia